# MiniDumpWriteDump with Callback in Go

Tags: windows, go, winapi, sdk, wdk

I'm trying to implement **MiniDumpWriteDump** with a **callback** in **Go**.

Call of **MiniDumpWriteDump**:

```
    callback := syscall.NewCallback(miniDumpCallback)
    var newCallbackRoutine MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INFORMATION
    newCallbackRoutine.CallbackParam = 0
    newCallbackRoutine.CallbackRoutine = callback
    ret, _, err := miniDumpWriteDump.Call(
        uintptr(processHandle),
        uintptr(processId),
        uintptr(dumpFile),
        uintptr(options),
        0,
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&newCallbackRoutine)),
    )
```

**Callback** function itself:

```
func miniDumpCallback(_ uintptr, CallbackInput *MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT, _ uintptr) uintptr {
    fmt.Println(CallbackInput.ProcessId, CallbackInput.CallbackType)
    return 1
}
```

**Type** definitions:

```
type MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT struct {
    ProcessId     win32.ULONG
    ProcessHandle win32.HANDLE
    CallbackType  win32.ULONG
    CallbackInfo  uintptr
}

type MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INFORMATION struct {
    CallbackRoutine uintptr
    CallbackParam   uintptr
}
```

Callback is called and some fields recieve the correct data, but some get **nonsensical** values.

For example, the callback above recieves the **ProcessId** field of **CallbackInput** correctly, but recieves random integers as **CallbackType**, when it shoud be recieving **MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_TYPE** enumeration.

Output:

```
12544 0
12544 1133445120
12544 12548
12544 13028
12544 1114112
12544 1023344640
12544 999620608
12544 990117888
12544 992542720
12544 1005518848
12544 1994850304
12544 1114112
12544 1994915840
```

Comment: Why did you choose to delete your previous question (including the helpful comments you received)?

Comment: That question did not recieve any correct answers. I tried the solution the comment you're refering to suggested, it did not work.
This version of the code is cleaner and offers relatively more correct way of registering callback.
I deleted the previous question because it did not hold any value to the community, and in addition, displayed the wrong usage of the callback functions.
I posted this, the new one with the same title, so other developers will find more correct and easily understandable code, when they try to research this subject.

Comment: I don't know anything about Go but I'm guessing the issue is in the alignment for the MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT struct. Assuming you're running on x64, alignment is going to be 8 bytes.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, something like this should be done, right? @Luke 
```type MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT struct {
 ProcessId     uint32
 _ [8]byte
 ProcessHandle windows.Handle
 _ [8]byte
 CallbackType  uint32
 _ [8]byte
 CallbackInfo      uintptr
 _ [8]byte
}```

Comment: Structures in *minidumpapiset.h* have 4-byte alignment (on all platforms). For 32-bit architectures, things should just work as that is that natural alignment for all types used here. For 64-bit architectures you'll have to force memory layout to 4-byte boundaries and cannot rely on Go's natural memory layout for structures.

Comment: To verify this you can read the `ProcessHandle` field, extract the upper 32 bits, and see if that 32-bit value matches the expected `MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_TYPE` value. If it does then the issue is with structure packing. As I understand, Go doesn't support non-natural structure packing, so your callback will have to receive a byte slice instead, and parse out the individual fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments suggested, the problem was with **structure alignment**.

As @IInspectable explained, minidumpapiset.h, which exports MiniDumpWriteDump function and MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT struct, uses **4-byte** alignment for both, **32bit** and **64bit** architectures, while Go uses **8-byte** alignment by default for 64bit and offers no automatic way of changing it.

The solution is to manually read the struct. Here's a worknig example:

```
type MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT struct {
ProcessId     uint32
ProcessHandle uintptr
CallbackType  uint32
CallbackInfo uintptr}

func ptrToMinidumpCallbackInput(ptrCallbackInput uintptr) MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT{
    var input MINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INPUT
    input.ProcessId = *(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(ptrCallbackInput))
    input.ProcessHandle = *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(ptrCallbackInput + unsafe.Sizeof(uint32(0))))
    input.CallbackType = *(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(ptrCallbackInput + unsafe.Sizeof(uint32(0)) + unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))
    input.CallbackInfo = *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(ptrCallbackInput + unsafe.Sizeof(uint32(0)) + unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0)) + unsafe.Sizeof(uint32(0))))
    return input}
```

The original code should work fine on 32bit architectures, since it's padding(4-byte) matches with the padding minidumpapiset.h uses.